# http post request for android

Tags: java, android

I want to send POST request in java for android.

I Use this code :

```
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("myUrl");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("artist", "Amy Macdonald"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("title", "Don't Tell Me That It's Over"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("album", "Don't Tell Me That It's Over"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
```

The problem is that when i use :

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

i get an exception, and this webservice is working for sure,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What scheme are you posting to? http or https? Have you set up the client correctly with a `ClientConnectionManager` and `HttpParams`? What exceptions are you getting in your logs?

The only difference I see between some code I have for posting data (assuming your client is setup correctly) is that I use httpContext in the execute method like this:

```
httpPost = new HttpPost(urlString);
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));
response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, httpContext);
statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

where the context is setup in the constructor with

```
httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
httpContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, new BasicCookieStore());
```

If you are using https, you'll need to setup the client with more information so it can handle the keystore requirements and other secure aspects of the connection.

Answer (score 0):

The [Javadoc](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/NameValuePair.html) States:

> A name / value pair parameter used as an element of HTTP messages.

```
 parameter               = attribute "=" value
 attribute               = token
 value                   = token | quoted-string
```

Since HTTP POST doesn't append attributes to an URL (per say), It does it in a form of Entity Body. You can have a simple string based entity or MIME based entity body.

`NameValuePair` has implemented classed called [`BasicNameValuePair`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/message/BasicNameValuePair.html) which (think of it LIKE HTTP parameters) you provide a parameter and a value.

Answer (score 0):

Check this post

http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-get-post-and-multipart-post-requests/

It got all type : *httppost, httpget, httppost with file upload*....